# Yii2 funtional test not work with configured componets

Tags: php, yii, yii2, functional-testing, codeception

I'm using Yii2 basic template for an application, where most of the config is in `<yii-home>/config/web.php` which includes `<yii-home>/config/params.php`.

The functional test should only start the index-action in look for an headline and looks like this:

```
class StartPageCest
{
    public function _before(\FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage(['site/index']);
    }

    public function _after(\FunctionalTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function tryToTest(\FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->see('hello', 'h2');  
    }
}
```

But this results in an error:

```
 Test  tests/functional/StartPageCest.php:tryToTest
  [Error] Call to a member function get() on null
```

Going trough the index action I found this line, where the test stops:

```
$result = Yii::$app->cache->get('site_index_result');
```

So it looks like, that the caching component is not initialized. (by the way, there is also an Solr component in this action, where the test stops also).
Probably the config coming from `<yii-home>/config/web.php` is not loaded in the test-runtime. Could this be?

My `functional.suite.yml` looks like this:

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - Filesystem
      - Yii2:
          configFile: config/testconfig.php
```

and this is the content of the `testconfig.php`

```
$config =  yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(

        require(__DIR__ . '/web.php'),
    [
        'id' => 'app-tests',       
    ]
);

return $config;
```

So my questions are:

1. How could I debug the test in oder to see, what is loaded and which infomrations are avalaible at test-runtime?
2. How could I load the application config into the test environment?

Comment: Dear unknown Person, I have no idea, why you downvote this question. Probably there is something wrong with the lines I wrote. But in this case it would be helpful if you leave a comment, why. That would be a constructive way of avoiding mistakes in the future.